# Need help in the Regular Expression start with string with space

Tags: python, regex

I want the string start with "shivam " (without quote).my regular expression is :`(?=shivam\s)\w+`
but they are not matching space after shivam what do i do?

Input is:

```
shivam gupta
```

Expected output is:

```
gupta
```

Without any space both side. My output is `shivam gupta`.

Comment: You have `\s` in the lookahead, but the main consuming pattern does not match it. Use `^(?=shivam\s)\w+\s+` (the `^` will match the start of the string). Or easier: `^shivam\s`. Best is `s.startswith("shivam ")`

Comment: i want the all result  exclude "shivam " but start with that

Comment: What is the language? Use `^shivam\s+(.*)` and grab the group 1 contents. See https://regex101.com/r/mnPY3n/1

Comment: using lookhead what can expect ? not any specific lang (globally)

Comment: Why do you need a lookahead at all? Please share the code.

Comment: your result also give shivam in output which i don't want

Comment: As I said, ony take Group 1 contents.

Comment: shivam should not include in result which is included in your result

Comment: let me know how to take gp 1 content

Comment: What is the language/tool you plan to use the regex in? How are you using a regex? Surely I could say "use [`(?<=^shivam\s).*`](https://regex101.com/r/mnPY3n/2)", but lookbehind is not supported by all engines. Also, if there are two spaces between `shivam` and `gupta`, the result will contain a `gupta` with initial space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to learn a bit of a regex use

```
import re
s = "shivam gupta"
m = re.match(r"shivam\s+(\w+)$", s)
if m:                 # Check if the pattern matches the string
    print(m.group(1)) # print only Group 1 contents
```

See the [Python demo](http://ideone.com/ldhwWD)

The `re.match` method only searches at the start of string, so `shivam` is looked for at the start. Then `\s+` matches  one or more whitespaces, and finally, `(\w+)$` matches *and captures* into Group 1 one or more word chars and then the end of string `$`.

The Group 1 contents are accessed via `.group(1)` of the match object (here, `m`).

However, you can use string methods and a split operation here:

```
s = "shivam gupta"
if s.startswith("shivam "):
    print(s.split()[1])    # or even print(s[s.find(" "):])
```

[Another demo](http://ideone.com/hZCxR3).